# Looking into weird protocol-buffer message (decoding and encoding)

Tags: protocol-buffers, decode

I'm trying to figure out, is there a way to create a .proto definition, which could create and decode a message that looks like this:

```
parent_field {
   carrier_field { (field id: 1)
       subfield_1: 10 (field id: 1)
       subfield_2: 20 (field id: 2)
   }
   carrier_field: "string" (field id: 1)
}
```

which means that under same field identifier I can get either sub message or a string.

I tried something like:

```
message MessageWrapper {
   message ParentField {
      message SubMessage {
          ....
      }
      repeated SubMessage carrier_field = 1
   }
   ParentField parent_field = 1
}
```

but when I try to decode the message I get:

```
# protoc --experimental_allow_proto3_optional  --decode MessageWrapper proto_definitions/test.proto < test.buff 
Failed to parse input.
```

How should the .proto definition look like to be able to decode and encode a message showed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way of doing that would be for `carrier_field` to be a `bytes` field that you would then separately decode as either a string or a protobuf message. Frankly, I'd advise against this: it would be better to use a `oneof` with different field numbers.

Comment: This might be the worst solution, but still if there is no other way to use optional field with same id - I guess it's the only option.

Comment: @Marcin there is one other idea... you could have two versions of ParentField - a ParentFieldString and a ParentFieldSubMessage, and deserialize the right kind contextually. Protobuf doesn't know the message type - it isn't in the metadata - so this will work as long as the data is valid

Comment: the issue here is, that both message types come within one request/response, so I guess the only option is to treat them as binary and then do some coding to decode right field correctly (in this case first should be decoded from binary as nested message, the second as string).